# Sort in mongoDB using a specific order

Tags: c, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently looking to sort the sub document, `Clients`, in a particular order based on an array.

The mongoDB structure is

```
{
    "_id" : "1033",
    "Name" : "Test",
    "Clients" : [ 
        {
            "Id" : 1033,
            "Types" : [ 
                {
                    "Class" : "C",
                    "Service" : null
                },
                {
                    "Class" : "B",
                    "Service" : null
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 156136,
            "Types" : [ 
                {
                    "Class" : "A",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "B",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "C",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "D",
                    "Service" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the above document displayed in the order based on a array like `[B, A, D, C]`

So that the output would be as below:

```
{
    "_id" : "1033",
    "Name" : "Test",
    "Clients" : [ 
        {
            "Id" : 1033,
            "Types" : [ 
                {
                    "Class" : "B",
                    "Service" : null
                },
                {
                    "Class" : "C",
                    "Service" : null
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : 156136,
            "Types" : [ 
                {
                    "Class" : "B",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "A",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "D",
                    "Service" : null
                }, 
                {
                    "Class" : "C",
                    "Service" : null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you please help me on how to achieve this?

I am currently using MongoDB Driver for .Net

Comment: If you need a **single** document **displayed** with it's array items ordered in a fancy way it would be better to sort them client side really.

Comment: @AlexBlex is right. You will have to do that client side. Mongodb does not support such ordering; only ascending or descending.

Comment: @OdamePrince, it is possible to do it with aggregation, but even if you can, it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @AlexBlex, there will be multiple documents like this

Comment: Do you fetch/display all of them at once? You don't sort documents, only `Types` items within a document, unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: We do sort it by name also, and by the internal types. We will be showing 5 documents at a time

Comment: So let mongodb to sort documents by name, and then sort the types in the representation layer. To make it crystal clear, sorting subdocuments on the database level is quite expensive. It is no cheaper than doing it on the client  anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Custom ordering is possible via aggregation as specified [here](https://koenaerts.ca/mongodb-aggregation-custom-sort/).

Comment: This actually helps to sort fields with values like `High`, `Medium`, `Low` that won't get sorted correctly by the default behavior of `sort()` in mongo

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my problem with custom sorting , using $addFields and $indexOfArray aggregations.

let imagine that my document has two fields: BouqetId, Name

```
[
    { "BouqetId" : 2, "Name" : "Name2"},
    { "BouqetId" : 16, "Name" : "Name16"},
    { "BouqetId" : 25, "Name" : "Name25"},
    { "BouqetId" : 15, "Name" : "Name15"},
    { "BouqetId" : 125, "Name" : "Name125"},
    { "BouqetId" : 258, "Name" : "Name258"},
    { "BouqetId" : 127, "Name" : "Name127"}
            ... 
  ]
```

and I want to search for Bouqet with Ids **[258,15,2,16]** and get them with this order.

1/ I filter my collection using $in operator in $match aggregation  to get the required documents: view step one in code.

2/ I add a field using $addFields aggregation named Order and assign to it the index of the BouqetId in the searched array using $indexOfArray aggregation.

3/ finally I sort them using the newly added Order field.

4/ I get my custom-ordered result. I can remove the order field but it is ok for now.

here and exmaple in Nodejs :

```
var db = client.db("MyDatabase");
var collection = db.collection("Bouqets");
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "BouqetId": {
                "$in": [
                    258,
                    15,
                    2,
                    16
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "Order": {
                "$indexOfArray": [
                    [
                       258,
                       15,
                       2,
                       16
                       ],
                    "$BouqetId"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Order": 1.0
        }
    }
];

var cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Here my result :

```
[
    { "BouqetId" : 258, "Name" : "Name258" , "Order" : 0},
    { "BouqetId" : 15, "Name" : "Name15", "Order" : 1},
    { "BouqetId" : 2, "Name" : "Name2", "Order" : 2},
    { "BouqetId" : 16, "Name" : "Name16", "Order" : 3}
]
```

here the same example in c# :

```
       IMongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://host:port/");
       IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
       IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Bouqets");

       var options = new AggregateOptions()
       {
           AllowDiskUse = false
       };

       // my array 
       var searchArray = new int[] {258, 15, 2, 16}; 


       PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
       {
            new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument()
                .Add("BouqetId", new BsonDocument()
                    .Add("$in", new BsonArray(searchArray)
                    )
                )),
            new BsonDocument("$addFields", new BsonDocument()
                .Add("Order", new BsonDocument()
                    .Add("$indexOfArray", new BsonArray()
                        .Add(new BsonArray(searchArray)
                        )
                        .Add("$BouqetId")
                    )
                )),
            new BsonDocument("$sort", new BsonDocument()
                .Add("Order", 1.0))
       };

       var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline, options).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom ordering is not possible in MongoDB. You can either sort ascending or descending.